# My Ubuntu USB Boot Drive Prompts nothing on startup?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, troubleshooting

Hello Ubuntu Community.

I'm trying to set up a USB Live Boot from my Windows 10 machine, but I'm not having any success. I've used Rufus dozens of times with varying configurations, ran block scans, clean slated my USB more than once, configured my BIOS, and used the two most recent LTS versions of Ubuntu. Though every time I boot from the USB, I'm met with a black screen or a frozen BIOS. The only action I can take is the power button. Haven't gotten the setup dialog once after many attempts.

My PC specs are below and Rufus configuration are below. I'm using a PNY 64GB USB 3.0. Also, I'm not going anywhere for a few hours, so if you need more information, I'll get back to you soon.

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks all.

[Device Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mimYg.png)
[Rufus Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNBl6.png)

Comment: Try balenaEtcher. Is simpler to setup.

Comment: Will do. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Please do. Unlike Rufus, Etcher does a 1:1 copy and the resulting media boots either in Legacy or UEFI mode. Your settings for Rufus are wrong because you want UEFI mode for ANY 10 years old or newer computer.

Comment: I've attempted once thus far, and I've gotten the same result. I suspected UEFI mode is the way to go as Windows startup options tends to respond to that. I tried another config on RUFUS using the NSFT filesystem with UEFI mode and I got a prompt this time, but it wasn't Ubuntu related. It froze up after attempting to launch an .efi file.

Comment: No luck. The furthest I've gotten was using a configuration with Rufus, was formatting to NSFT, a GPT Partition Scheme, for a UEFI system. I finally get output that it detects something and it attempts to launch bootx64.efi, but never gets beyond that point. I'm investigating the directory its searching in to see if the file exists, and if it doesn't I wonder if it would be possible to pull it from somwhere.

Comment: Okay, so the drive absolutely has /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi, but it doesn't get past launch. Any insights?